# Can I put radial-gradient into a image

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<div class="right">
     <div class="img">
          <img ng-src="{{ticket.thumbnail}}">
     </div>
</div>
```

And this scss

```
.right{
      width: 25vw;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;

      background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, $mainBackground 9px, transparent 9px),
      radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, $mainBackground 9px, $footer 9px);
      .img{
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;

        img{
          height: 16.2vh;
        }
      }

    }
```

The result of this is:

[image]

I want to have both borders like the right one. I know to do it with a solid background, but not with an image. The one I know to do is:

[image]

Thanks a million

**EDITED**

I tried to put the image like background of .right class:

```
<div class="right" ng-style="{'background-image' : 'radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, #150357 9px, transparent 9px),
          radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, #150357 9px, url({{ticket.thumbnail}}) 9px)'}">

</div>
```

The problem is that it doesn't show nothing:

[image]

The html output is:

[image]

I thinK that if I could show the image in the background place, it should be work like a want.

Comment: Question unclear imho.

Comment: I need help thanks!

Comment: Dude if I say question unclear it means I'm asking for more information or other wording. Shouting "I need help" won't bring you anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I can't do it in an image. I should edit first